# Datatables yadcf plugin multi_select with custom data

Tags: jquery, datatables, yadcf

I am using the YADCF plugin for an online index I have created.  It works very well but I am trying to implement the multi_select option with specified keywords.  What happens is that the list just appears in full where the multi_select should be and the muliselect doesn't work at all but filtering does.  Here is how I implement it

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    oTable = $('#plex').dataTable({
    "scrollCollapse": true,
    "paging":   true,
    "pageLength": 15
}).yadcf([
    {column_number: 0, filter_type: "text"},
    {column_number: 1},
    {column_number: 2},
    {column_number: 3, filter_type: "multi_select", select_type: 'select2', data : [<?php $list = implode("," , $filter); echo $list; ?>]},
  ]);
});
```

As you can see I load the data filters from a database, this works fine.  My expected output would be like the example on the webpage where I would be able to select 2 filters to filter down my table but that isn't happening.  Thanks in advance

Comment: by saying "list just appears in full" you mean that the select element got no styles of the select2 plugin and just appears as "plain select with multiple mode enabled" (pressing ctrl for multi select) ? if so yo must verify that you included select2 js/css/etc... provide a screenshots / jsbin sample with your issue (instead of data from server provide dummy values)

Comment: I will include screenshots.  Basically the styling does not hide the list.  I'm not even 100% sure if it can do what I want it to

Comment: You can achieve at least what you can see in the showcase http://yadcf-showcase.appspot.com/DOM_source_select2.html